# Ideas for static website generator that produces HTML and PDF from single LaTeX / MathML source?

Tags: pdf, html, latex

I'm looking for a tool that can generate both a static (but responsive) website and also PDF output from the same LaTeX-enabled source. I'd like to have 'chapters' in the PDF output be 'tabs' in the HTML output, the 'Table of Contents' for PDF become the site map for the HTML, and a hyper-linked index for both. The source would include text, graphics (both images and generated canvas graphics), and mathematics, with the output in LaTeX for PDF generation and MathML/HTML for the web.

The closest tool I've come across so far is https://www.madoko.net/ which does most of what I'm looking for. However, it's quite server-centric, and uses a one-off 'Koka' language that makes modification difficult. I haven't found anything else that even comes close though.

This is for a personal static website (actually an experimental aircraft build log) so performance, scalability, and all that is not an issue. My dev environment is Gentoo Linux, so TexLive, pandoc, etc. are all available. However, I'd rather not roll my own custom tools for this if I can avoid it. Has anyone come across any static website generators that can generate both a fluid website and a PDF 'book' of an entire site using one set of source files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make high quality PDF reports, presentations and interactive websites using [R Markdown and RStudio](https://rmarkdown.rstudio.com). LaTeX and BibTeX support is built in; and it uses [pandoc](https://pandoc.org) to convert `.rmd` files to other output formats (including PDFs and HTML pages).

In fact, if you want to organise your content like a book, then you should take a look at the [bookdown](https://bookdown.org) package for R. As I said before, support for LaTeX equations, theorems, and proofs is built in.

Here is an [example website](https://otexts.com/fpp2/ses.html).